# @Gateway is not required if we use @MessagingGateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

From Spring 4.0 onwards `@MessagingGateway` was introdued. Using it if we have only one gateway method in our Gateway interface , then we don't need to annotate the Gateway method with `@Gateway`.
Below is my example, where both are working.

So, my question is can we stop using `@Gateway` when we have only one method in Gateway interface?

Code-1:

```
@MessagingGateway(name="demoGateway")
public interface DemoGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "gatewayRequestChannel",replyChannel = "nullChannel")
    void accept(Message<String> request);
}
```

Code-2:

```
@MessagingGateway(name="demoGateway",defaultRequestChannel = 
"gatewayRequestChannel",defaultReplyChannel = "nullChannel")
public interface DemoGateway {

    void accept(Message<String> request);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You are right. You can do approach 2 and leave the single method that confirms to the default configuration of `@MessagingGateway` without annotation.

However in practice, I will only move the truly default values to the `MessagingGateway` and leave other values to `@Gateway` annotation.

This is because it makes life and readability easier in the future if you have to add more methods to `DemoGateway` in the future.